# Show content only if there are one or more relationships

Tags: relationships, solspace-calendar

Using Solspace Calendar, I am displaying a list of related entries (from a relationship field) on an individual event page, like so:

```
{exp:calendar:events event_id="{embed:event_id}"}
<section id="related-orgs">
<div class="hd">
    <h2>Related Organisations</h2>
</div>
<div class="bd">
    <!-- Start Entry Listing -->
    <ul class="entries compact">
        {event_organisations}<li class="entry"><a href="#">{event_organisations:title}</a></li>{/event_organisations}
     </ul>
    <!-- End Entry Listing -->
</div>
</section>
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

This is pulling through the related entries correctly.

**However, if there are no related entries, I don't want that section to appear at all.** I have tried using `count` and `total_results` as per the below, but this appears to prevent it from showing even when there are relationships.

```
{exp:calendar:events event_id="{embed:event_id}"}
{if event_organisations:count == "1"}<section id="related-orgs">
<div class="hd">
    <h2>Related Organisations</h2>
</div>
<div class="bd">
    <!-- Start Entry Listing -->
    <ul class="entries compact">{/if}
        {event_organisations}<li class="entry"><a href="#">{event_organisations:title}</a></li>{/event_organisations}
     {if event_organisations:count == event_organisations:total_results}</ul>
    <!-- End Entry Listing -->
</div>
</section>{/if}
```

Am I missing an obvious solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need to show calendar data in this part of template, why not to use the traditional channel:entries module?

Plus, you're checking for the position in the loop **outside** the loop!

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{embed:event_id}"}
    {event_organisations}
    {if event_organisations:count == 1}
        <section id="related-orgs">
            <div class="hd">
                <h2>Related Organisations</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="bd">
                <!-- Start Entry Listing -->
                <ul class="entries compact">
    {/if}
                    <li class="entry"><a href="#">{event_organisations:title}</a></li>
    {if event_organisations:count == event_organisations:total_results}
                </ul>
            <!-- End Entry Listing -->
            </div>
        </section>
    {/if}
    {/event_organisations}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I've tried it but the section doesn't appear at all when using channel:entries, even when there are relationships to show.

Comment: Of course! Eureka! Our code is completely wrong. I gonna fix it!